# How to determine if a user is actually looking at a web page?

Tags: javascript, events

Is it possible to determine whether a user is active on the current web page or, say, focused on a different tab or window?

It seems that if you switch tabs, any JavaScript set on a timeout/interval continues running. It would be nice to be able to 'pause' the events when the user is not on the page.

Would something like attaching a mouseover event to the body work, or would that be too resource-intensive?

Comment: Do you want to find out whether he is looking out of the window? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event)/[`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event) events on the `window`.

There's [wide support for those events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) on the window.

**Example:**

```js
window.onfocus = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>I've gained focus.";
};

window.onblur = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>I've lost focus.";
};
```

```css
span {color:blue}
```

```html
<span>CLICK IN AND OUT OF THIS FRAME.
    <br><br>(It has its own "window" object).</span>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) (and perhaps some other tracking tools) has [action tracking](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Action_Tracking)

Comment: Action tracking is a broken link

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [visibilityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState) of the document:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if( document.visibilityState === 'visible' ) {
    // Do your thing
  }
});
```

There is a [wide acceptance](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility) of this API.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an alive variable going using `mousemove` events (assuming the user does not leave the mouse still on the page). When this variable (a timestamp likely) has not been updated in x seconds, you could say the page is not active and pause any script.

As long as you do not do a lot of processing in the body event handler you should be okay. It should just update the variable, and then have a script poll it at a certain interval to do the processing/checks (say every 1000ms).

Answer (score 0):

Attach listeners to mousemove, keyup and scroll to the document.

I use this [throttle/debounce function](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) (which works without jQuery, even though it's a jQuery plugin if jQuery is present) to only run code in response to them once in ~250ms, so that you're not firing some code on every pixel of the mouse moving.